# prove: if $f(\frac{1}{n}) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

$f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable and $\exists L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f^{(n)}(x)| \le L$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I need to prove that given the information above: if $f(\frac{1}{n}) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $f(x)=0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Have no idea where to start, I tried to show that if $f(x) \not = 0$ for $0<x<1$
and $x \not = \frac{1}{n} , n \in \mathbb{N}$ then we will get unbounded derivative near $0$ , but even if I manage to show it formally it will only show that $f(x)=0$ for $0<x<1$ and not for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

EDIT: hope its better now

Comment: What properties does $f$ have?  Do we know that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Infinitely differentiable implies continuity

Comment: It's not clear whether f(x) being infinitely differentiable is give or something we need to prove.  If it's something to prove from just f(1/n), this is impossible and not necessarily true.  If we are give that f is infinitely differentiable and the derivatives are bounded... then f(x) = 0 is provable.  I think.

Comment: clarification: what properties of $f$ are *given* (as opposed to the properties that we are meant to prove)

Comment: I think we are supposed to give that f is inf differentiable and all derivatives are bounded by L, but the way the question is stated that isn't clear.  But if we are expected to prove those... well, obviously we can't.

Comment: Hypotheses come first, then the conclusion. Please edit and try to be clear.

Comment: Hint: consider 1/(n+1) < x < 1/n f(x) = c $\ne$ 0.  By intermediate value theorem for  some y in [1/(n+1), x], |f'(y)| $\ge$ |c/(x - 1/(n+1))| $\ge$ |c|$\times$n/n+1 and by iterating we'll find an $|f^k(w)| > L$ so f(x) is constant on an interval.  Repeat the argrument for any x off this interval and you'll find if f(x) $\ne$ 0 anyway there will be an $|f^k(z)| > L$ somewhere.

Comment: 1) if f is constant on an interval [a,b], then $f^k = 0$ on the interval.  Let f(x) > 0 a + 1 >x > a.  Then for some c in [b,x], f'(c) = [f(x)- f(b)]/x-b.  So for some d in [b,c], f''(d) = {[f(x)-f(b)]/(x-b)} /(c-b) $\ge$  {[f(x)-f(b)]/(x-b)} /(x-b) = $[(f(x)-f(b)]/(x-b)^2]$.  So there are points $d_k$ where $f^k(d_k) = [(f(x)-f(b)]/(x-b)^k$ which are unbounded values.  So if f(x) is constant anywhere, f is infinitely differentiable, and the derivatives are bounded.  Then f(x) is constant everywhere.

Comment: 2) if for $1/n < x < 1/(n-1)$ and f(x) $\ne$ but f(1/n)= f(1/(n-1) = 0$ then there are f' takes on negative and positive and 0 value on the interval [1/n, 1/(n-1)]  by same argument as 1) we can show therefore the collection of values of k-th derivatives is unbounded.  So ....

Comment: 3) given the hypothesis of inf differable and diff bounded and f(1/n) = 0 we must conclude f is a constant function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differentiability condition together with $|f^{(n)}(x)| \leq L$ tells us that the equality

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^{n}$$

holds for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We prove the claim by contradiction: Assume that there is a $x \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$, then there would have to be a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(n)}(0) \neq 0$. Let $N$ be the smallest such $n$. We can write

$$f(x) = x^{N}g(x), \quad \text{where} \quad g(x) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(N+n)}(0)}{n!} x^{n} $$

It follows that $g(1/n) = 0$, $n \in\mathbb{N}$ and $g$ is continuous, so we have

$$ 0 = g(0) = f^{(N)}(0)$$

contradicting the definition of $N$.

Comment: why do we need to know that all the derivatives are bounded by L, isn't the fact that f(x) is infinitely differentiable enough for the existence of  taylor-expansion  ?

Comment: @BorisMorozov no, an infinitely differentiable function does not necessarily admit a taylor expansion that converges anywhere except at 0.