# How to do this...

Tags: taylor-expansion

Let $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ verifying,

$a)$ exists $L>0$ : $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall n\ge 1$

$$|f^{(n)}(x)| \le L,$$

$b)$ $$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=0     \quad    \forall n\ge 1.$$

Prove that,
$$f(x)\equiv 0, \quad  \mbox {on} \quad \mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday: when it was found to be a duplicate, you deleted it. Now you are asking it again. This kind of behaviour is not tolerated here; please don't do this again!

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1768695/721644).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**. (a) Note that the Taylor series for $f$ at 0, that is 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n $$
converges to $f$ everywhere (use Taylor's theorem and the boundedness of the derivatives).

(b) Hence, both powerseries $\sum_n \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$ and $0$ agree on an infinite set with an accumulation point. That is, they are equal.

Comment: martini: Please see comment on main by @AlexM.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1.** The condition $$
\lvert\,f^{(n)}(x)\rvert\le L, \quad\text{for all}\,\,x\in\mathbb R\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,n\in\mathbb N, \tag{1}
$$
implies that the Taylor series of $f$ 
converges for all $x\in\mathbb R$, and hence $f$ is equal to
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)\,x^n}{n!},
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

As $\,f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=0$, then $f(0)=0$, because of continuity.

Assume now that $\,f\not\equiv 0$. In case, there would be a $k\in\mathbb N$, such that $\,f^{(k)}(0)\ne 0$ while $\,f^{(0)}(0)=\cdots =f^{(k-1)}(0) $. Then 
$$
0=n^kf\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=n^k\sum_{j=k}^\infty \frac{f^{(j)}(0)}{j!\,n^{\,j}}=\frac{f^{(k)}(0}{k!}+\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{f^{(j)}(0)}{j!\,n^{\,j-k}}\to \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}, 
$$
as $n\to\infty$, and hence $\dfrac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}=0$, which contradicts our assumption. Thus $f\equiv 0$.

**Method 2.** The condition $(1)$
implies that $\,f$ is real-analytic in $\mathbb R$, and hence it can be expressed locally (in fact, globally) as a power series.

The fact that $f$ is identically zero is a consequence of the following fact:

*If $f,g:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ are real-analytic and coincide in a set with has an accumumation point in $(a,b)$, then $f\equiv g$.*

In our case, $f$ coincides with $g\equiv 0$ at the points $\left\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb N\right\}$, which have $0$ as an accumulation point.

Comment: I did not understand the reason for which the limit = 0.

Comment: @Math123 Which limit? Are you talking about $\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{f^{(j)}(0)}{j!\,n^{\,j-k}}\to 0$?

Comment: Yes, I did not understand it

Comment: Yiorgos: Please see comment on main by @AlexM.