# Prove with Rolle or Lagrange

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ satisfy $$f(1/n)=0 \quad\forall
>  n\in\mathbb Z^+$$ Prove with Rolle or Lagrange that $$f(0)=0$$

Thanks.

Comment: Is using Rolle or Lagrange compulsory?

Comment: @vidyarthi yes.

Comment: otherwise, the proof is a direct consequence of Continuity definition.

Comment: Are you asking the same question as this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066972/how-to-do-this

Comment: .Which is? how?

Comment: Why is $C^{\infty}$ in the hypothesis. We know that $0=\lim_{n \to \infty} f(1/n)=f(0)$ by continuity alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter example to the earlier claim $f(x) = 0$:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & x \le 1 \\
e^{-1/(x-1)^2} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: But,$f(0)=0$, isnt it?

Comment: See the edit, the original post claimed $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: yes, I know .But the edited question is trivial using just the definition of continuity. What do you think?

Comment: Ok but how you are using the definition?

Comment: @Math123 A function $f$ is continuous iff for every convergent sequence $(x_n)$, $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}x_n\to x\implies \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\to f(x)$